# What is the best approach to deal with "small" individuals?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

I am wondering, what is the best approach to deal with "small" individuals? Let me clarify, suppose I have a Point. Point has Speed. Speed has unit and value.
So then there will be a lot of Points, may be this is a physical engine for example.
To create each Point one has to provide IRI, as well as for Speed individuals. But it looks like this is a tough exercise, I mean creating all this IRIs, from either memory value or semantics points of view.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Anonymous_Individuals ?

Comment: Yes, but it seems impossible to get all predicates with their values where this anonymous individual is a subject using its nodeID..

Comment: You have to ask yourself this question, Do you want to uniquely identify every point? If Yes, use IRIs else use blank nodes (anonymous individuals)